# Fluent validator: How to validate a string to be not empty when another field is specific value from enum

Tags: c#, fluentvalidation

I need to add validation for `Message` only when `Type` is `Other`

I tried to use `Must`, and validation works when type is `Other`, but when type is `First` I receive `"The specified condition was not met for 'message'.",`

```
 enum Types
 {
     First, Second, Other
 }

 class MyRequest
 {
    public string Message { get; set; }
   
    public Types Type { get; set; }
 }

 public MyRequestValidator()
 {
     RuleFor(x => x.Type)
         .IsInEnum();
     RuleFor(x => x.Message)
         .Must((model, field) =>
         {
             if (model.Type == Types.Other)
             {
                 return true;
             }

             return false;
         })
         .NotEmpty()
         .WithMessage("Message is required when type is Other")
         .MaximumLength(10);
 }
```

Any ideas how to validate a string when another prop is a specific value from an enum?

Comment: why not using ``When`` ?

Comment: @SaeedEsmaeelinejad good question :)

Answer (score 0):

looks like When proposed by `SaeedEsmaeelinejad` soled my issue

```
 When(x => x.Type == Types.Other, () => {
                RuleFor(x => x.Message)
                    .NotEmpty()
                    .WithMessage("Message is required when type is Other")
                    .MaximumLength(10);
            });
```